# XmNvisibleItemCount not returning correct number of items when window is resized

Tags: c, x11, motif

`XmNvisibleItemCount` is supposed to return the number of visible items in a list.  Unfortunately, it does not return the right values when I resize the window.

```
XtVaGetValues(myWidget, XmNvisibleItemCount, &vic, XmNitemCount, &ic, NULL);
```

The above returns `nine` every time, which is the number of items visible in the list when my window is opened.  When I resize the window, however, it is still `nine`!  Despite the visible items being `three` if I shrink the window or `eleven` if I expand the window.

How do I get `XmNvisibleItemCount` to return the right number of visible items in a list when a window is resized?

Comment: This smells strongly of the X-Y problem. What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XmNvisibleItemCount is not set by the widget during resize, but rather by the programmer when the widget is created. If the XmList is a child of a manager widget that manages its size, the attribute is ignored.

If you want to know the number of visible items (what would that be good for anyhow?), you need to calculate that yourself from the item height and the list dimensions.